# Error: Cannot find module 'curl' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

I installed `node.js` with the windows installer. The folder structure formed is `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`. The last node_modules has all the module folders I guess.

I use the node.js command prompt to execute my js script. When the script is on Desktop, it executes all fine. When I shift my script to another folder in my `C:` it gives the error. I don't want to give the absolute path as it will have to be changed again and again. Anyways, what path should I give as absolute to make it just work

```
Error: Cannot find module 'curl'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
```

I have gone through the resolutions mentioned in other discussions. Have made the NODE_PATH environment variable. Have edited PATH variable to make it `C:\Program Files\nodejs` and not `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`. Have executed `npm install -g npm` and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble, if anyone has already started looking into it. I found the solution. In the node.js command prompt, in the project folder I executed the following  'npm install curl' which downloaded the curl packages into a node_modules folder in the folder which has my script. I anyways wonder, then how it worked when I had placed my project on Desktop. It seems that the way node.js finds modules has to be checked. FYI - I have not set the NODE_PATH and the path still has C:\Program Files\nodejs\ after I freshly installed it. Thank you!